# Android makefile to generae the static executable

Tags: android, makefile

I am trying to generate the executable something like adbd in /sbin.

The executable I wish to have is iwlist with ARM format and the type is static.

I added the folder in the AndroidSourceCode/external and execute the "mm" command to compile

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ifneq ($(TARGET_SIMULATOR),true)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libiw

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iwlib.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDE += LOCAL_PATH

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iwlist.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libiw
LOCAL_MODULE := iwlist

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
#================================================

endif # !TARGET_SIMULATOR
```

The above make file actually works by generating the iwlist executable with

```
 iwlist: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses
 shared libs), stripped
```

However, I am looking for the "statically linked" and I was thinking "LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true" this line should help me make this executable statically.

Unfortunately, it doesnt.

Kindly instruct me if you know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone? This has puzzled me a couple of days....

Comment: Try building the static library instead of the shared library to compile statically.
change the line {include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)} to {include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem but I was not able to compile statically linked any file using the Android toolchain.
You can use another toolchain for that. I have tryied with the toolchain from linaro and It works fine.
You can download here:
https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/ToolChain

I downloaded the 4.7 version, untar the file place in my home directory.
To compile is as easy as:

```
~/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-2012.06-20120625_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  -static -s hello.c -o hello
```

Of course I recommend you to put that bin directory in your path.

That will create a statically linked file:

```
# file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, stripped
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Melopsitaco. This is really helpful for me. However, iwlist executable relies on the libiw, do you know how to compile them together? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the libiw.so and libiw.a for ARM you can compile together you have to include the library directory with -L and -liw to use that library. But I haven't found the ARM libiw in the Android crosscompiler...

Comment: Changing toolchain hardly seems like a portable fix for this. I have a similar problem, but can't change my gcc.